# Finding sum of a sorted array in O(log n) Time Complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

There is a Sorted Array A[1,..,n] where each element in the array is between [0-9] and numbers can be repeated with conditions i.e. A[i] <= A[i+1] *(less than equal to)*

Is there any way to compute this in O(log n) time complexity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use binary search to find the first occurrence of 0, then the first occurrence of 1, and so on all the way up to 9. That way, you'll know the exact count of `0's, 1's, 2's..` etc in the array.

Array sum = `(1's count*1) + (2's count * 2) ... (9's count * 9)`.

Total complexity = `O(logN)` for running binary search 9 times.

**Edit**:

Count of `x` in the array will be

```
If `x` isn't the largest element
count(x) = (first index of the next greatest number) - (first index of x)

Else
count(x) = length of array - (first index of x)
```

Comment: The worst case complexity is - `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: @H.S. can you explain the reason behind your complexity analysis?

Comment: What would be the complexity for this input - [`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`]?

Comment: @H.S. what would be the complexity for running binary search 9 times?

Comment: `9` time when only `9` elements in the array in this form - `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Think about it.

Comment: The question specifically mentions: "each element in the array is between [0-9]". So what is the issue?

Comment: There is no issue. The worst case scenario where each number between `[0-9]` occur only once i.e. for this array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` the complexity is `O(nlogn)`. Of course, the average case complexity will be `O(logn)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recommended answer, How can you get to know the count of each element in the array? My understanding is, the binary search will give you the first occurrence of that element, but you still need to know the elements greater or lesser than that to count the occurrence and in doing so you will still traverse the whole array, resulting in O(N). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that bit

Comment: Looks like a comment rather than an answer. Please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment